# Can we count the points in polygon using pyqgis code?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, python-2.7, point-in-polygon

Does anyone know how to calculate the point in polygon from the given points and the buffer output using python qgis.
I have every thing loading the data and retrieving the output. But now I want to count the points in polygon. I was checking this [link](http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/11/tip-count-number-of-vertices-in-layer.html) but that didn't work.

Code:

```
    from PyQt4.QtCore import *
    from PyQt4.QtGui import *
    QgsApplication.initQgis()
    uri = QgsDataSourceURI()#4326

    #loading fisrt layer with multistring
    uri.setConnection("localhost","5432","db_name","postgres","password")
    uri.setDataSource("schema_name","table_name","column","")
    vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(),"LayerName1","postgres")
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)

    #loading second layer with points around it

    uri.setConnection("localhost","5432","db_name","postgres","password")
    uri.setDataSource("schema_name","table_name","column","")
    vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(),"LayerName","postgres")
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)

    #creating buffer
    mc = iface.mapCanvas() 
    layer = mc.currentLayer()
    print layer.name()
    QgsGeometryAnalyzer().buffer(layer, "C:/Users/***/aa.shp", 0.0004, False, False, -1)

    #loading back buffer
    layer1 = iface.addVectorLayer("C:/Users/***/aa.shp", "layer_name", "ogr")
    layer1 = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()

#point in polygon
    provider = layer.dataProvider()
    provider.select()
    feat = QgsFeature()
    vertex_count = 0
    while provider.nextFeature(feat):
          geom = feat.geometry()
          if geom.type() == QGis.Polygon:
            layer_vertices = 0
            if geom.isMultipart():
              polygons = geom.asMultiPolygon()
            else:
              polygons = [ geom.asPolygon() ]
            for polygon in polygons:
              for ring in polygon:
                layer_vertices += len(ring)
            print "Feature %d: Vertices %d" % ( feat.id(), layer_vertices)
            vertex_count += layer_vertices
            print "Total vertices: %d" % (vertex_count)
```

## ERROR:

provider.select()
AttributeError: 'QgsVectorDataProvider' object has no attribute 'select'

Also please can you guys share the link or the code for counting points in polygon. Few of them posted the same error can anyone share the code with explanation for point in polygon.

Answer (score 2):

In the QGIS source code, you will find the Python code for the **Points in Polygon** tool ...

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/fTools/tools/doPointsInPolygon.py

Not sure why you are coding this from scratch. You might want to have a look at Processing which allows to combine these existing tools into automated workflows.

Comment: I have a huge data for processing qgis that doesn't load and it is working when I upload it. And I don't want to keep hitting the stuff like add layer and other things everytime. So once I code it would keep iterating everytime I just need to save the name of files into a list. We could do multiprocessing  so several tasks would be happening in parallel and finish earlier.